# How to run background node process with vscode and without node on client machine

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I would like to run a node process in the background of my VS Code extension (something that will stay alive even after shutting down VSCode).

The target machine does not have node, but only has VSCode installed.

I have tried using `fork` with the env variable `ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE = 1` and `detached` as follows:

```js
const { fork } = require('child_process');
fork('path to js', {detached: true, env: {...process.env, ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE:'1'})
```

This works as expected, however the process seems to die when I close or restart VS Code.
The child process seems to be using the VS Code renderer process (I guess that's why it dies).

Anyone tried this or suggestions on how i could run a node process in the background on a machine with VS Code & not have Node installed.

Comment: Found that it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Found that it works as expected when not debugging VS Code extensions.

However when debugging extensions in VS Code then for some reason the child processes are also killed. Could be something to do with the Debugger.

To be clear, the problem I was having was the child processes were getting killed while I was debugging VS Code.